# JavaScript Radio Buttons on Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, form-submit

So I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to create a simple code that'll allow the person to choose `binary`, `hex`, or `oct` and convert a decimal number to the chosen radio button. Now i'm not worried about the conversion at this point, I'm just trying to get the code to run a function after I hit submit. For example, if radio button binary is selected, once the submit button is clicked, on the page it should say "binary selected."

I'm really lost as to how to get this to work and not sure where to look. I keep changing my code i got it to work when you select the button it generate "object selected", but i want it to generate only after the submit button is pressed. Unsure if i have to code the submit button or the form tag. My current, non working code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>


  function convertit()
  {
   
   var conversion = document.getElementsByName('convert');


   if (conversion[0].checked == true) 
   {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Binary Checked";
   }


   else if (conversion[1].checked == true)  
   {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = " Hex Checked";
   }

   else if (conversion[2].checked == true)  
   {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "Oct Checked";
   }

    else
   {
    alert("Empty");
   }
   return true;
  }

 

 


  </script>
 </head>




 <body>

  <p id="test"> </p>

  <form onsubmit="return convertit();">
   <input type="radio" value="binary" name="convert" id="binarybut"  >
     Binary 
   </input>

   <input type="radio" value="binary" name="convert" id="hexbut" >
     Hex
   </input>

   <input type="radio" value="hex" name="convert" id="octbut"> 
    Oct
   </input>

   <input type="submit" value="Convert Number" > 


  </form>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is fine, just return `false` from the handler so that the default form submit will be prevented. Your form is getting submitted which is causing the page to refresh thus it is going to the default state

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tm1aoukx/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! So glad it was a simple fix, I've been going crazy all day trying to get it to work. Thank you!!! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript can't find your output element because it's not declared yet.

If you put your < script >...< /script> at the end of the body, it should work fine.

eg:

```
...
< /script>
< /body>
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fejp8jg/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>

  function convertit()
  {
   
   if (document.getElementById('binarybut').checked) 
   {
                                alert("Binary Checked");
   }


   else if (document.getElementById('hexbut').checked)  
   {
           alert("Hexadecimal Checked");
   }

   else if (document.getElementById('octbut').checked)  
   {
                                 alert("Octal Checked");
   }

    else
   {
     alert("Empty");
   }
   return true;
  }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <p id="test"> </p>

  <form>
   <input type="radio" value="binary" name="convert" id="binarybut"  >
     Binary 
   </input>

   <input type="radio" value="binary" name="convert" id="hexbut" >
     Hex
   </input>

   <input type="radio" value="hex" name="convert" id="octbut"> 
    Oct
   </input>

   <button type="button" onclick="convertit()">Convert</button>


  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ssheatler Dose this answer your question you can run the code and try CSS can be done later after completing the functionalities

Comment: any luck this is what you required right @ssheatler